# How to get messages from telegram chat?

Tags: c#, console-application, telegram, telegram-bot

I am using `Telegram.Bot` library.

I now need to do one thing: **delete messages older then 3 months.**

My bot is an Administrator, with full permissions to chat. Tried ForwardMessage from firstID to lastID, to another chat, with another bot, this works, but I think it is so silly...

I'm stumped, can you prompt me with ideas, how to do it. Just need to get all messages, with dates.

Comment: There's a [deleteMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) method. Get the messages ids you want to delete and run such method

Comment: thanks for help, i know about this method, but how can i get ids? only loop from first?